# printing from php to real printer

Tags: php, printing

I have been using the following script for some time now in a batch file to print PDF files to a printer:

```
c:\path\to\PDFtoPrinter.exe c:\path\to\file.pdf "\\ip\printer"
```

I had hoped to simply add this to a PHP script using exec() and all would work, but no.

```
exec('c:\\path\\to\\PDFtoPrinter.exe c:\\path\\to\\file.pdf "\\\ip\\printer"');
```

My other idea was to write the commands to a bat file and execute that file from my PHP script, but also no success.

Any suggestions?

```
exec("\\path\\to\\PDFtoPrinter.exe \\path\\to\\file.pdf '\\ip\printer'");
```

Comment: A single quote literal as you have with `exec()` does not escape those backslashes. Remove the double backslashes, or use a double quote literal instead.

Comment: Also the way this is written you would be missing a backslash before ip

Comment: Like my last line?

Comment: It would be correct to do `exec("\\path\\to")` that is with escaping the backslashes. Only double quote literal will respect the escape chars. But not correct with the single quote, because then each char is taken literally.

Comment: So my last line should be correct?

Comment: Bro share your email and I can send the whole code to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
exec("c:\\path\\to\\PDFtoPrinter.exe c:\\path\\to\\pdf.file \"printer-name\"");
```